# get the text inside '[ ]' tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know how to ask this properly but I need to get the text inside the [] tag and make it a variable

fox ex. i have :

```
<p>[something][written]</p>
```

I need to get the word **something** from [something] and make it a var
and same goes for [written] so i can have something like this :

```
var text1 = something /*-only the word-*/
var text2 = written /*-only the word-*/
```

to use it like :

```
<span>there is '+text1+' '+text2+' here.</span>
```

Of course it's not how i will use it, but they're kind of similar. Is it possible? sorry I'm completely a newb. thanks in advance.

Comment: `var something = ???`

Comment: Can the brackets be nested? If not, you can use a very straightforward regex. Otherwise you'll need to actually tokenize/parse the input yourself.

Comment: hi Bhojendra Nepal.. what i mean is something like var text1 = something (the word only wthout the brackets)

i dont actually understood what you are saying @collinD sorry..

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.text()`, `.match()` with `RegExp` `/\[[a-z]+\]/ig` to match `[text]`, `.map()`, `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\[|\]/` to remove `[`, `]` characters

```js
var [something, written] = $("p").text().match(/\[[a-z]+\]/ig)
                           .map((t) => t.replace(/\[|\]/g, ""));

console.log(something, written);

var span = `<span>there is ${something} ${written} here.</span>`;

$("body").append(span);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>[something][written]</p>
```

Comment: This edited version might solve my problem and is easier to understand than the previous one. Thanks! :)

Comment: can you please help me a little further? this worked well on jsfiddle but when i added it to my site i keep getting this error and i don't know what's to be done.. 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text(...).hide is not a function'

Comment: Is jQuery defined? Try substituting `function(){}` for arrow functions, concatenating variables for template literal

Comment: im starting to learn the 'traditional' way of coding, i don't know anything about this arrow functions and concatenating variables until now :( could someone help me translate them? T^T

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Here is a solution that you can even try with console

```
<script>
var text = "<p>[Something][Written]</p>";
var inBrackets = text.split('[');
for (var i = 1; i < inBrackets.length; i++)
{
    console.log(inBrackets[i].split(']')[0]);
}
</script>
```

Goodluck!

**EDIT:** Here you get every word that is in a bracket and assign them to a var.

Comment: I corrected my answer, Sorry for the eariler downvote. This is written only in javascript and can run flawlessly. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex `\[(\w+)\]`, the obtained words within `[]` will be filled in the array `res` then you can use them through js:

```
 var str = \\ obtain your text from the element(s) through JS
 var res = str.match(/\[(\w+)\]/g);
```

Comment: Just as a word of caution to OP, this cannot handle nested brackets properly. It also cannot match `[word1 word2]` or `[word.word]` but the question is unclear as to whether those are considerations to be made or not.